# Check if a path matches a DOS search pattern like *.txt

Tags: .net, windows, glob

I'd like to check if a given path matches a search pattern like `*.*` or `report*.txt`.

`Directory.GetFiles (root, "*.txt")` or similar should not be used (the file in question does not even exist).

My first idea was to translate the search pattern to regex, but I recall the search pattern behaves somewhat strangely at times (presumably for historic reasons), so it can probably not easily be translated.

Comment: [This](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2007/12/17/6785519.aspx) might be helpful - but do you really care about the strange behaviour, or do you just need to support simple cases?

Comment: @Blorgbeard Thank you, that is an interesting link. It also shows that there were some very strange things, and (only) some of them were fixed in Windows 95.

Comment: I've thought about it again and I'll be fine with simple cases that I can emulate with something like regex. But others might not, so I'll leave this question up for reference, in case someone finds an answer.